# Get count in Laravel after grouping without using get()

Tags: sql, laravel-5, eloquent

```
$countQuery = $countQuery ->groupBy("something");
$totalCount = $countQuery->get()->count();
```

In $countQuery there are joins also. I want to get the final count without get()

Comment: You can get count without get. Did you try   $totalCount = $countQuery->count();

Comment: Yes, I tried. But then it returns count as 1. The problem is having groupBy.

Comment: Try :
$query = $countQuery;
$countQuery = $countQuery->groupBy("something");
$totalCount = $query->count();